# Append Data to JSON - array_merge

Tags: php, array-merge

I'm trying to append some data to json, but the output (`[[],[],[]]`) isn't what I expected
Here's my code:

```
$utenti = json_decode('{"123":[],"456":[]}', true);
$newUtenti = ["789" => []];
$newUtenti = array_merge($utenti, $newUtenti);

echo json_encode($newUtenti);
```

What am I doing wrong? 
This is the expected output: `{"123":[],"456":[], "789": []}`

Comment: What are you expecting as the output?

Comment: something like this: {"123":[],"456":[], "789": []}